# Insert Timestamp into Varchar2 column in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with an application that interfaces with an Oracle 11g database. I need to insert a timestamp in the *YYYYMMDDhhmmss* format, into a Varchar2 column.

My SQL update query is:

update CODELIST_XREF_ITEM set RECEIVER_ITEM=**TIMESTAMP** where LIST_NAME='BUSINESS_PROCESS';

The **TIMESTAMP** variable is where it need to be inserted. I have tried setting the **TIMESTAMP** variable to *CURRENT_TIMESTAMP*, however I am not able to format that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: have not worked with oracle for a while but try 'update CODELIST_XREF_ITEM set RECEIVER_ITEM=to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYYMMDD HH24MISSFF') where LIST_NAME='BUSINESS_PROCESS';'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert the character representation of a timestamp (it actually appears that you want the character representation of an Oracle `date` since you don't want fractional seconds or a time zone), you'd use the `to_char` function.

```
to_char( sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
```

So your `UPDATE` statement would be

```
update CODELIST_XREF_ITEM 
   set RECEIVER_ITEM=to_char( sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
 where LIST_NAME='BUSINESS_PROCESS';
```

If you wanted to store fractional seconds or a time zone or do something else that required a `timestamp`, you'd use the same `to_char` function just with a different format mask.

Comment: Make sure you mark this answer as approved so Justin gets credit.  Thanks.